# Python socket irc bot - socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, shared-libraries

```
args = b'' 
for index,item in enumerate(arg) : 
    if index > 3: 
        if args == b'': 
            args = item 
        else : 
            args += b' ' + item

elif data.find(b'!scan') != -1:
    nick = data.split(b'!')[ 0 ].replace(b':',b'')
    targetip = socket.gethostbyname(str(arg))
    sck.send(b'PRIVMSG ' + chan + b" :" + ' scanning host' + targetip + b'\r\n')
    for i in range(20, 1025):
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        result = s.connect_ex((targetip, i))
        if (result == 0) :
            s.send(b'PRIVMSG ' + chan + b" :" b'port %d: OPEN' % (i,) + b'\r\n')
            s.close()
```

I get socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed when I try to scan a specific IP. the command in IRC is (!scan IP). The bot just exits and gives me the error above.

the purpose of arg is to find the string or argument after !scan which is the IP. Example: !scan arg.

Comment: If you put `print(str(arg))` right above `targetip = socket.gethostbyname(str(arg))`, what does it display?

Comment: I get [] I guess an empty string? @Kevin

Comment: Hmm, strange. An empty string wouldn't display anything at all. `[]` suggests that `arg` is a list with no elements. I don't think it makes sense to call `gethostbyname` on something like that.

Comment: it works when i changed socket.gethostbyname(str(arg)) to str(socket.gethostbyname(args)) but the bot outputs "scanning host0.0.0.0" and then it gives me this error, NameError: name 'AF_INET' is not defined.